# How can I separate hour and minute digits from a date string

Tags: php

I have, for example the string 2013-12-08 19:55:19 and from this string I want to obtain 19:55. How can I do this in PHP?

Comment: Where are you stuck? What have you tried? Why didn't that work out the way you wanted?

Comment: Is there a space in between the time and date or a T?

Comment: explode on space. substring() to drop last 3. if the format never changes, just substr() can do it

Comment: preg_split on space, access the array at subscript 0 for your time.

Comment: Or assuming you got that date from MySQL, use its native date formatting functions to get it in the original query.http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: don't use preg_split, just for a space

Comment: Why not use some date time functions?

Comment: @RPM invoking the regex engine (if it isn't already in use) is really expensive.

Answer (score 1):

You can go parsing the datetime to an object and stuff, or you can simply do:

`substr($myString,11,5)`

(take 5 characters starting from the 11th character)

Only condition is that your string always has 4 digits for the year. And 2 digits for all other elements. Just like in your OP

Answer (score 0):

Check out `strtotime()` and `date()`:

```
echo date('G:i', strtotime('2013-12-08 19:55:19'));
```

Comment: Uhhh, gets 19:55 (hour and minutes) as the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex:

```
$str = "2013-12-08 19:55:19";
preg_match("/.*(\d\d\:\d\d)\:\d\d\.*/", $str, $arr);
echo "time: " . $arr[1];
```

**OUTPUT**

```
time: 19:55
```